# Can I access __asm variables from outside an __asm block?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I know that it's possible for an `__asm` block to access variables declared outside of those blocks, but what I want to do is find a way to access a variable declared in an `__asm` block from outside such a block.  All my knowledge of C and C++ indicates that this should be impossible because of the way C and C++ scopes anything within `{}` blocks.  Is there a way to do this or am I required to declare such variables outside of the `__asm` block?

PS:  I have not been able to find any relevant answer to this question from any of my searches.

Comment: I guess we assume you are using MS Visual C++?

Comment: Yes, but isn't inline assembly available on other compilers?

Comment: It is available (but not required) in other compilers but not always offered in a way that is compatible with MSVC++. For instance in GCC there are assembly language templates that work quite differently from the MSVC++ ones.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: how you declare variables in `__asm` block ? at all use inline assembler bad idea and not supported with x64. much better add to project separate asm file. with this you can access from asm any c++ symbols (except *static* ) and from c++ - asm symbols and functions (if they name acceptable for c++)

Comment: "how you declare variables in `__asm` block?" - Wouldn't they be declared in the same manner as if they were in an ASM file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be No

> **Microsoft Specific**
>
> Although an __asm block can reference C or C++ data types and objects, it cannot define data objects with MASM directives or operators. Specifically, you cannot use the definition directives DB, DW, DD, DQ, DT, and DF, or the operators DUP or THIS. MASM structures and records are also unavailable. The inline assembler doesn't accept the directives STRUC, RECORD, WIDTH, or MASK.
>
> **END Microsoft Specific**

From here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx